# AVAudioPlayer sends "Unsupported file" error when playing a file recorded via AVCaptureSession

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I've been scratching my head around this a full day now and don't seem to get closer, so I hope you guys can guide me in the right path :)

Heres's the situation.

I have a AVCaptureSession properly initialized where I add the audio input as follows :

```
let audioDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio)
        let audioIn = try! AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: audioDevice)

        if (session.canAddInput(audioIn)) {
            session.addInput(audioIn)
        }
```

The audio output is added as follows :

```
if session.canAddOutput(self.audioOutput) {
        self.audioOutput = AVCaptureAudioDataOutput()                
        session.addOutput(self.audioOutput)
        self.audioConnection: AVCaptureConnection = self.audioOutput.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio)
}
```

I then setup the recording settings :

```
        if let audioAssetWriterOutput = self.audioOutput.recommendedAudioSettingsForAssetWriterWithOutputFileType(AVFileTypeAppleM4A) {
        return audioAssetWriterOutput as? [String: AnyObject]
    }
```

which I assign to my AVAssetWriterInput that is initialized in audio mode, with those settings and the correct format description.

_audioInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio, outputSettings: audioSettings, sourceFormatHint: audioFormatDescription)
_audioInput!.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = true

then I just simply start the AVCaptureSession via `startRunning()` that will capture the audio data into a .M4A file.

Everything is fine during the audio capture, here are the observations that I made :

1. The file recorded exists on disk as expected
2. The file can be played by any player : my mac, my iphone (I imported it via iTunes), seems all good.
3. The file is at the correct location when I setup my AVAudioPlayer.
4. Tried to initialize the AVAudioPlayer with NSData or NSURL, same result

Now later in my code, I try to read that audio file via an AVAudioPlayer :

```
self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathLink] error:&error];
```

I get thrown an error

```
Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=1954115647 "(null)"
```

which after double checking is "Unsupported type".

What's incorrect in my setup ? Does this come from my AVCaptureSession or can something be wrong with my AVAudioPlayer setup ?

Thanks !

Comment: try to load your audio as data (nsdata), then to init audio player with that data

Comment: already tried ...same result. I'll add this to the question, thanks !

Comment: try to use URLWithString instead of fileURLWithPath

Comment: tried that as well @LeoDabus

Comment: I'm using .m4v files

Comment: but your codec it is audio not video AVFileTypeAppleM4A so you should be using .m4a

Comment: sorry typo, I'm using .m4a files ! AVFileTypeAppleM4A

Comment: What codec is the audio in the file using?

Comment: @quellish could you explain your request ? I'm using AVFileTypeAppleM4A and AVMediaTypeAudio whenever an input/output type is setup.

Comment: @Champoul the file type is m4a, that is just a wrapper. The data inside the wrapper can be encoded in many different formats. QuickTime Player, etc can tell you this. AAC-LC would be one example of a codec.

Comment: thanks, I see AAC, 44100kHz, Mono, which is exactly what I'm going for. Data rate of 85kbps